# Bulk insert using raw sql (mysql) not working with load data infile and ignore # lines

Tags: mysql, django, bulkinsert

I'm trying to insert rows using raw sql in django:

The input file has 15 lines that are "commented out" using '#'.

The rest of the file is tab delimited and terminated by '\n'.

I am trying to ignore the first 15 lines using the IGNORE <#> LINES clause in my LOAD DATA INFILE statement.

using the following code:

```
def my_custom_sql():
    from django.db import connection, transaction
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    statement = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/dev/ttam/data/temp.ttam' INTO TABLE ttam_genotypeentry (snp_id, @dummy1, @dummy2, genotype) SET subject_id=%i IGNORE 15 LINES;" % subject.pk
    cursor.execute(statement)
    transaction.commit_unless_managed()
```

i get the following error:

```
DatabaseError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IGNORE 15 LINES' at line 1")
```

With the statement (removing the IGNORE 15 LINES):

`statement = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/dev/ttam/data/temp.ttam' INTO TABLE ttam_genotypeentry (snp_id, @dummy1, @dummy2, genotype) SET subject_id=%i;" % subject.pk`

I get this error:

```
IntegrityError: (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ttam_genotypeentry`, CONSTRAINT `snp_id_refs_rs_id_50bcd16b` FOREIGN KEY (`snp_id`) REFERENCES `ttam_snp` (`rs_id`))')
```

If i manually remove the first 15 lines of the input file, the operation continues without issue.

I am using:

django: `Django version 1.3 rc 1`

mysql: `Server version: 5.1.49-1ubuntu8.1 (Ubuntu)`

How do i ignore the first 15 lines of my input file?

Comment: You don't seem to have the IGNORE n LINES clasue in the first code sample you posted.

Comment: oops editing now. Bad pasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the `IGNORE n LINES` clause to before the `SET` clause.

`statement = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/dev/ttam/data/temp.ttam' INTO TABLE ttam_genotypeentry (snp_id, @dummy1, @dummy2, genotype) IGNORE 15 LINES SET subject_id=%i;" % subject.pk`

Comment: Dang, I was sure I saw it after the set in the reference manual. Thanks.